# How to display arrays

Tags: java, arrays

**I'm trying to display a array board for my tic-tac-toe game.**

The board is supposed to look like this:

> 123
>
> 456
>
> 789

*However when I run the program it shows up like this:*

> 150
>
> 159
>
> 168

**My Code:**

```
 class TicTacToe


{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    { 
       char [][] board = {{'1','2','3'}, {'4','5','6'}, {'7', '8', '9'}};

        System.out.println(board[0][0] + board[0][1] + board[0][2]);
        System.out.println(board[1][0] + board[1][1] + board[1][2]);
        System.out.println(board[2][0] + board[2][1] + board[2][2]);


   }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those values you see are the addition/sum of the character in there decimal values in the [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/):

```
'1' = 49
'2' = 50
'3' = 51
```

equals

`150`

What you need to do is add/append an empty string instead of adding the characters decimal value

```
System.out.println(board[0][0] +""+ board[0][1] + board[0][2]);
```

Comment: Or use a String array instea, but what ever ;)

Answer (score 3):

This is a consequence of the fact that the `char` values you're attempting to print are being added mathematically instead of being concatenated.  The Unicode values of the `char`s representing the numbers `'0'` through `'9'` are `48` through `57`, respectively.

So, adding `'1'`, `'2'`, and `'3'` means adding `49`, `50`, and `51`, which sums to `150`, which is printed.

Include an empty string at the beginning, so that `String` conversion takes place as the values are concatenated from left to right, and that the `char`s are added as you expect, e.g.:

```
System.out.println("" + board[0][0] + board[0][1] + board[0][2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is a much more efficient method** (takes all the manual work out) that will blitz through larger array tables with ease and yours as well (it may look complex but give it a quick look):

```
class TicTacToe {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
       char [][] board = {{'1','2','3'}, {'4','5','6'}, {'7', '8', '9'}};

        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {       //loop rows

           for (int j = 0; j < board[0].length; j++) { //loop columns
              System.out.print(board[i][j]);           //print columns
           }
           System.out.println();                       //print space for the next row
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the sum of character code (see [ASCI](http://www.asciitable.com/) table)
`1`=49
`2`=50
`3`=51
49 + 50 + 51 = 150

To print character representation indicate the string concatenation as below:

```
class TicTacToe
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   { 
     char [][] board = {{'1','2','3'}, {'4','5','6'}, {'7', '8', '9'}};
     System.out.println("" + board[0][0] + board[0][1] + board[0][2]);
     System.out.println("" + board[1][0] + board[1][1] + board[1][2]);
     System.out.println("" + board[2][0] + board[2][1] + board[2][2]);
   } 
}
```